# Cannot remove right scrollbar in Vim

Tags: linux, vim, linux-mint

In my `~/.vimrc` I have `set guioptions-=r` for no right scroll bar. Unfortunately, I still see the right scrollbar in vim (run in terminal), although I cannot scroll it.

This is my `~/.vimrc` file:

```
set nocompatible      " We're running Vim, not Vi!
syntax on             " Enable syntax highlighting
filetype on           " Enable filetype detection
filetype indent on    " Enable filetype-specific indenting
filetype plugin on    " Enable filetype-specific plugins

" Toggle paste with F2 so that pasting from external applications goes well
nnoremap <F2> :set invpaste paste?<CR>
set pastetoggle=<F2>
set showmode

" Mapping ctrl-c ctrl-space to intellisense
inoremap <expr> <C-Space> pumvisible() \|\| &omnifunc == '' ?
            \ "\<lt>C-n>" :
            \ "\<lt>C-x>\<lt>C-o><c-r>=pumvisible() ?" .
            \ "\"\\<lt>c-n>\\<lt>c-p>\\<lt>c-n>\" :" .
            \ "\" \\<lt>bs>\\<lt>C-n>\"\<CR>"
imap <C-@> <C-Space>

" Ruby and Rails preferences
set term=xterm-256color"
colorscheme wombat256mod
set guifont=Monaco:h12
let g:NERDTreeWinPos = "right"
set guioptions-=T " Removes top toolbar
set guioptions-=r " Removes right hand scroll bar
set go-=L " Removes left hand scroll bar
autocmd User Rails let b:surround_{char2nr('-')} = "<% \r %>" " displays <%%> correctly
:set cpoptions+=$ " puts a $ marker for the end of words/lines in cw/c$commands 

" Transparent background
hi Normal          ctermfg=252 ctermbg=none
hi NonText         ctermfg=250 ctermbg=none

" Display line numbers
set number
```

I hope someone can tell me how to get the scrollbar removed.

Comment: which terminal do you use? very likely the scroll bar came with your terminal setting

Comment: Standard Linux Mint terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have set **gui** options-=r for no right scroll bar. [...] in vim (run in **terminal**), although I cannot scroll it.

Why do you expect a GUI-specific option to have any effect in a non-GUI program?

The scrollbar you see is your terminal emulator's, not Vim's.

If you want to get rid of that scrollbar, disable it in your terminal emulator's settings.

Comment: Ah of course! I can remove the scrollbar from the terminal, but then it is removed *everywhere*. I only want no scroll bar while running Vim. I can imagine that this is impossible.

Comment: Why did I assume you were using iTerm?

Comment: Don't know? I am running Linux Mint and have the default terminal there.

Comment: I can still scroll up by selecting text. I disabled the terminal scrollbar and am happy. :-) Plus I discovered the `:Sex` command to browse directories. Once I have (pretty) highlighting of all instances of hovered variable and can properly copy and paste text (the fact that x also copies is something I want disabled, I can do that with "d" if I am not mistaken), Vim will start to surpass my other editor. The fact that it is *in* the terminal is amazing.